# Remove periods from url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I've seen variations of this question around, but I couldnt make it work for me.
My problem is: I have many urls indexed at google where the address has one ore more periods. Ex: http://partiturapara.com.br/15-sheets/809-some-music-enc.4.5

Of course the URL does not work, because Apache thinks it is a extension, so I have to strip them, to leave something like this:
http://partiturapara.com.br/15-sheets/809-some-music-enc45

I have a few .htacces lines that make things work (I use joomla) that I will show them bellow.
I´ve tried the following:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.([^/]*)\.$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]` - But it just keep loading for ever
and also tried:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.$ /$1 [NC]` - This almost works, but gets terrible slow and url will not finish loading.

If you could at least point me in the right direction it would be amazing, cause I already spent lots and lots of hours trying to figure out how all these lines works together and its been very frustrating.

My actual rewrite at the .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # ----- The line I inserted ------
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.$ /$1 [NC]
    #-------My edit end  --------------
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

**EDIT 1**
----------------- UPDATE AFTER JON´S SUGGESTION (it didnt work)----------------------

Hi, 
After Jon suggestion, I am trying to figure out yet how my htaccess files works. This way I removed all lines in a way the website still works. The Line Jon suggested seems to be ignored. This is minimum .htaccess I got:

```
RewriteEngine On

------ this is the line Jon suggested me  -----
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.([^/]*)\.$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
------ end line Jon sugested -----------------

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

As I said, the website navigates normally, except when it finds the "dot" in the URL, so it returns the error:

*Not Found
The requested URL /15-partituras/1046-sentimental-o.d.m-v-choro was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

Perhaps I misunderstood something?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to insert that rule there. You've completely usurped the very necessary conditions that need to be applied to the index.php routing rule. `RewriteCond`'s only apply to the immediately following rule.

Try adding this right below `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.([^/]*)\.$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hello!First, thank you very much for spending your time to help me. Unfortunatelly it didnt work. Nothing happens now. I mean: The website still works as before. Load normally the URLS without dots but it still dont work in urls with dots. I will complement my question, with my effort to simplify the htacess files.